# What is the most efficient way to "encode" a finite field into a structure that has only one binary operation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, binary-operations

I know that a finite field can be easily encoded into and decoded from a finite Paige loop, which can be defined as a Moufang loop that is simple and isn't a group. However, the finite Paige loop of a field of order $q$ has about $q^7$ elements. Is there any more efficient way to encode a field into a type of structure specified by axioms such that every structure of that type can be uniquely decoded?

Comment: Moufang loops are defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moufang_loop)

Comment: A recent article looking *apparently* [connected](https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.07486) (I am not expert at all in this domain!)

Comment: I know the definition of Moufang loops.

Comment: As for that article being "connected," I don't think so because it isn't about "encoding" fields.

Comment: No doubt you know them ! This reference was evidently given for people who don't know necessarily them (it is a good habit to give this kind of reference in your questions).

Comment: I think a good method might be to compactify the Zech logarithms.

Comment: Is there any simple method to "decode" the Paige loops?

Comment: Maybe decoding the Paige loops is harder than I thought...

Comment: I think the next step would be some binary-operation thing with Desarguesian projective planes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

Let $(F,+,\cdot)$ be a field. Define $T=A\times B$ where $A$ is the abelian group $(F,+)$ and $B$ is the commutative monoid $(F,\cdot)$.

The operation in $T$ encodes both operations of $(F,+,\cdot)$ simultaneously, and you can "decode" them separately by projecting onto the first and second coordinates.

Now, perhaps you mean that I'm supposed to give a set of axioms of some sort of algebra and that whatever such object is chosen, it has to give rise to a unique field.  I do not have any scheme in mind for that.  (One could just define products of pairs of commutative monoids and demand the two coordinates interoperate on the diagonal the way a field has to, but that's hardly pretty.)

What I'm describing above at least accomplishes the goal of encoding and being able to be decoded from the encoded state, and apparently only has $q^2$ elements and one operation, which seems to be very "efficient" as far as how many elements it needs.

Comment: @mathlander It does not contain $q^2$ elements, it contains $q$ elements.  Good luck finding an axiomatized type!  Well, as I mentioned you can just define your axiomatized type to be pairs of commutative monoids and then laboriously write out all the stipulations the operation has to satisfy for the split-operations to work out, that would do it.

Comment: In some sense, you would be trading off the field axioms for separate operations in for a hairier axiom system for a single operation.

Comment: That's basically the whole point of my question.

Comment: There you have it then.   I think I accomplished what you asked for, but it is not as you would have imagined :)

Comment: Excellent. I think I should call these "compactifields." What is the binary operation in T, anyway?

Comment: I don't really think that an operation like the one you described exists, but we can easily accomplish it with $q^2$ elements by defining (a, b) x (c, d) as (a + c, b x d).

Comment: @mathlander That is the definition of the operation in $A\times B$, of course.  Why do you say it doesn't exist when you see as well as I do that it does?  Also, you don't need the full $q^2$ elements.. you just need the diagonal $T$.

Comment: The binary operation on two things in T is not guaranteed to result in something in T.

Comment: @mathlander Ha, oh yeah :) I forgot about that. Definitely not a monoid itself then.  I take back what I said earlier then. My thing would need $q^2$ elements, and would contain superfluous information. But the diagonal would be enough to decode.

Comment: I think you might want to edit your post to signify that (I have been banned from suggesting edits).

Comment: @mathlander Gladly... let me know if I missed anything.

Comment: I don't think such an axiom system exists because the multiplicative group is always cyclic.

Comment: For the decoding process, you reference "projecting." How exactly do you define it in a way such that the decoding has the distributive property?

Comment: There can't be any structure besides the binary operation.

Comment: @mathlander The operations recovered via the projections are the same ones that went into building their contents... how could they stop being distributive?

Answer (score 1):

Each element of the new set is a pair of a point and a line in the Desarguesian projective plane over the field. Define a binary operation on two points of this set as the element corresponding to the line passing through both of them. Since Desarguesian planes are self-dual, this also corresponds to the operation given by the intersection of two lines. It is simple to define the axioms. There is one step that I'm missing here, but somehow uniquely define which point corresponds to which line. Each field generates a unique plane-structure this way. There should be a simple way to decode a plane-structure into a field. If anyone can complete these two steps, we would get a structure with about $q^2$ elements.

Comment: Ah, you're only interested in finite ones. I guess that's fair then.  It's a reasonable idea, but a far cry from a set with a binary operation... Of course planes will have their _incidence relations_ but even with them it seems like you need a little extra to recover both operations.